# Make sure a user verified their email before signing them in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm in the middle of adding firebase email/password sign in inside a React app. Specifically, it's an e-commerce site, and users will be signed in anonymously before they create an account (for things like cart data).

Here's the ideal user flow:

1. User registers by providing an email and password
2. User is not signed in immediately and instead gets a verification email
3. If a user tries signing in before verifying their email, they cannot sign in
4. User then clicks on the verification link and can sign in

I'm having issues with #3 because it appears like the only way to check if an email is verified is by calling:

```js
const { user } = await firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
if (user?.emailVerified) //let them enter the dashboard
```

However, this process signs in the user even if the email is not verified. That destroys the data on the anonymous account. And merging the two accounts isn't possible because the user thinks they are not signed in (hence it could cause UX issues if the accounts are already merged).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [email+password provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth), there is no way to prevent the user from signing in without a verified email address. You can of course keep them from using your app and accessing data, but you can't keep them from signing in.

If you want to ensure the user can only sign in after their email address has been verified, consider using the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth). You can then later allow them to set a password on the same account, either through the Admin SDK, or by creating a email+password account and linking that with the email link account. Also see the documentation on [differentiating email/password from email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#differentiating_emailpassword_from_email_link) for some of the nuances here.